# problema al crear JSON

Tags: php, json

muy buenas tardes, comunidad me esta pasando que al crear un json este me trae los datos duplicados de la siguiente Manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el json vemos dos veces duplicad ala misma información y solo necesita la que tiene los nombres de los campos si de pronto alguien conoce la solcucion muchas gracias... no se que mas se necesita para que me ayuden ya que soy nuevo comentando este tipo de problemas gracias estoy trabajando con vue,

---

como estas Claro que si mira
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la funcion o metodo que realiza la petición a la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la función en vue que me captura el response devuelto y me los guarda en un modelo o variable tipo array

---

Cedano Gracias claro tienes razón al no pasar un parámetro en  la consulta el proceso por defecto era traer toda la información con un índice por el  filtro de  fetch que trae por defecto. Aplique tu metodo y funciona perfectamente,  ahora me surge una duda con tu explicación,  respecto a este punto ya que lo implemento y no me funciona  $this->db_conexon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  lo estoy haciendo de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la consola de google muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero creo que es refiriéndose al json Vacío si de pronto sabes el motivo de por que la implementacion de esa maner no funciona te lo agradezco ya que me gustaría tenerla global  para evitar redundancia

Comment: Puede ayudar mas si colocas el código desde donde estas generando tu json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow y paso a explicar la causa del problema y propongo una solución.

#### Causa del problema

La causa por la que te duplica los datos es porque estás leyendo los resultados con el *fetch_style* por defecto del método `fetch` que es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

Como dice el Manual de PHP:

> `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (**predeterminado**): devuelve un array indexado
>   tanto por nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0
>   tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados. <sup>*</sup>

Es justamente lo que ocurre en tus resultados, tienes los datos dos veces, uno con array de índice numérico y otro con array asociativo.

---

#### Solución

Usar un *fetch_style* más específico. Para estos casos se suele usar `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

> `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las
>   columnas del conjunto de resultados.<sup>*</sup>

Sólo tienes que pasar el *fetch_style*  del siguiente modo:

```
while ($dataCl=$datosC1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $all_data[]=$dataCl;
}
```

Et... voilà.

---

#### Nota adicional

El *fetch_style*  por defecto se puede cambiar. Por ejemplo si siempre vas a usar `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` puedes pasar al constructor un array de opciones, donde indiques el modo por defecto:

```
$pdoOptions=array (
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                  )
```

Esta es la forma recomendada, para de paso poner en ese array otras configuraciones importantes como establecer el juego de caracteres, desactivar las preparaciones emuladas, establecer el manejo de excepciones.

O bien puedes hacer con `setAttribute`, una vez creada la conexión:

```
$this->db_conexon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Si haces esto antes luego podrás usar `fetch()` como lo tienes en tu código y no te duplicará los resultados.

---

<sup>*</sup> Ver el apartado [`fetch_style` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: Muy bien tu solución excelente

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en tu consulta dentro de la funcion `sucursalesCLientes($id)` cuando en la variable `$query` no le asignas el `id`, solo estas buscando todos los registros sin filtro, asignale el `id` que recibes como parametro en la funcion de esta forma:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cliente_sucursal WHERE Nit_cliente='".$id."'";
```

(recuerda no colocar imagenes del código sino el código en texto para facilitar las respuestas):

Comment: dale lo tendré en cuenta muchas gracias, por tu ayuda